# Screensaver with active desktop

Tags: windows-xp, screensaver

I am running XP and im looking for a screensaver that does not change the desktop. I.e when the screensaver is active, i want to be able to see my desktop as it is and any changes on the desktop to be visible. Only if i touch the mouse should the login prompt be displayed to inactive the screensave.

For example, i am usually either working on my desktop or laptop. On my desktop i have an applicaiotn running that is showing me stock quotes from the stock exchange. Everytime the screensaver activates i have to touch the mouse to bring the screen back.

What i want to be able to do, is to be working on my laptop and at any time look at the numbers on my desktop without the screensaver interfering. I want the screensaver to be active but its only job is to ask me to enter the password to unlock the screen. I should still be able to see teh stock prices as tehy are changing even while the screensaver is active.

Basicly is it possible to see the desktop while the screensaver is active?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [KidKeyLock](http://download.cnet.com/Kid-Key-Lock/3000-18512_4-185000.html) seems to fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of a screensaver was to prevent "burn-in" effects - which were exhibited by CRTs. When a static image was displayed for a long time, it would cause the phosphorous coating on the CRT to "burn" away and hence screensavers were developed to project moving images to prevent the burn-in effect ("screen saver").

Perhaps [Desktop Lock](http://www.toplang.com/desktoplock.htm) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that i was looking for an open source version. The desktop that i want to leave as active will have lots of numbers flowing through so it wont be a "Static image".

Comment: I was mentioning why a screensaver was developer :)

Comment: I cannot seem to find any decent opensource software.