# Lock screen without screensaver

Tags: windows, windows-xp, screensaver, password-protection

We run a [Wall display](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Radiator+View+Plugin) for our Jenkins continious integration server on an old windows XP machine. We want to be able to lock the machine, while still displaying the web browser.

Windows screen saver allows for the option to 'prompt user for password' when returning from the screensaver. How can this be accomplished without displaying the screensaver?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/197915/screensaver-with-active-desktop?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the lock screen is to hide the operation of the system and prevent unauthorized access. It sounds like what you want is half that - just lock the keyboard. It would be like the old days when computers had that round keyhole that disabled the keyboard. Sigh, those key switches are a thing of the past. But, you may want to try something like what is described here:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/11570/disable-the-keyboard-with-a-keyboard-shortcut-in-windows/